# Packages with same name in local debian repo are not visible

Tags: repository, debian

I've created a local repo on a local web server.  Some packages have unique package names; other packages have the same name as existing packages in the standard Ubuntu repos but they have different version numbers.

I want to install these packages with "sudo apt-get install *package*=*version*" - this works fine for packages with unique names but for packages with the same name as existing packages, the version in my local repo is not available.

For example I have packages libck_3.0.5.rw-0ubuntu1 and libck-dev_0.3.5.rw-0ubuntu1.  The first does not overlap an existing package (the standard ubuntu package is libck0_0.4.4-1) and I can install my package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libck=3.0.5.rw-0ubuntu1
```

However when I try this it fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libck-dev=3.0.5.rw-0ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.0.5.rw-0ubuntu1' for 'libck-dev' was not found
```

How can I configure my repo or server so I can install my local packages by version number?